# Load more using gridview removing previous items after fetching new data

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I want to implement loadmore with gridview and I am facing problems.
I am able to fetch new data on scroll and I am able to see new views itself. but previous views are disappearing.
I used notifyDataSetChanged().
But still this problem exists help me.

Here is my activity code
setting on scroll method in oncreate

```
   grid.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {

                if (stopLoadingData == false) {
                    // FETCH THE NEXT BATCH OF FEEDS
                   listBikes();
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

listbikes is server call to fetch data on scroll.
In Processlistener method i will set the data to adapter.

```
 bikeList = (CollectionResponseBike) result;
        mCursor = bikeList.getNextPageToken();
        items = (ArrayList) bikeList.getItems();

        Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Bike>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Bike lhs, Bike rhs) {
                String id1 = ((Bike) lhs).getTitle();
                String id2 = ((Bike) rhs).getTitle();
                return id1.compareTo(id2);
            }
        });
        grid.setAdapter(new BikeCustomGrid(BikeGridList.this,items));
        loadingMore = false;
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Adapter code is here

```
public BikeCustomGrid(Context c, ArrayList<Bike> mItems) {
    mContext = c;

    items = mItems;
    mLayoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(c);
    VolleySingleton mVolley= VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext);
    mImageLoader=mVolley.getImageLoader();
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Please let me know the solution for this. thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call your database just add the new data into same list(don't replace it) and don't call the constructor again and again make some method in adapter to provide list and after that just notify the adapter.

Something like this:

```
 mItems.addAll(yourListData coming from server or local db)
 adapter.addItems(mItems);
```

method in adapter:

```
public addItems(List list){
  items.addAll(list)
  notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```